# ACF Link элемент не находит произвольной таксономии

Tags: wordpress, acf

Есть произвольная таксономия, созданная для произвольного типа записи вот таким кодом.

```
function create_impact_areas_taxonomy() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Impact Areas', 'taxonomy general name', 'am'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Impact Area', 'taxonomy singular name', 'am'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Impact Areas', 'am'),
        'all_items' => __('All Impact Areas', 'am'),
        'parent_item' => __('Parent Impact Area', 'am'),
        'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Impact Area:', 'am'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Impact Area', 'am'),
        'update_item' => __('Update Impact Area', 'am'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Impact Area', 'am'),
        'new_item_name' => __('New Impact Area Name', 'am'),
        'menu_name' => __('Impact Areas', 'am'),
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'impact-area'),
    );

    register_taxonomy('impact_areas', array('resources'), $args);
}

add_action('init', 'create_impact_areas_taxonomy', 0);
```

На странице, я добавляю [элемент Link](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/link/) из плагина `ACF` но он не дает выбрать элемент этой кастомной таксономии по умолчанию. Можно ли как-то это испаравить ?

[image: acf link]

Comment: Используйте поле ACF Taxonomy. Link не предназначено для таксономий. Либо добавьте ссылку вручную.

Comment: Может всё таки есть возможность, как-то заставить ACF проводить поиск и по таксономиям для данного элемента ? * просто я не могу гарантировать, что во всех случаях ссылка клиента будет вести именно на таксономию. А если прописывать фиксированый адресс сылки то скорее всего при перемещении баз данных между сайтами оно его не переделает на нормальную (я сообственно так и решил данную проблему, но есть подозрение, что оно будет работать не корректно.)

Comment: `то скорее всего при перемещении баз данных между сайтами оно его не переделает на нормальную` -- обычно производится некий search/replace при помощи сторонних средств, при переезде.

Comment: Что же касаемо поиска, то наверное Вам будет проще собственное поле написать, чем пытаться туда прикрутить поиск по таксономиям. Как минимум до версии 5.6 для получения заголовков и ссылок использовась page specific функции, по типу `get_the_title()`, `get_permalink()` и наверняка есть еще ряд мест, которые просто не будут работать с таксономиями, так как аякс ответ формирует объекты, где скорее всего используются те же функции для получения данных записи, которые не применимы к таксономии.